# Javafx 3D disapear in split pane

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-3d

I developed a 3d plotting tool (so-called A; which is a subscene). I want to put this subscene in a Split Pane (B). The problem is a part of my scene disappears (when I rotate the plot some parts appear). as you can see below:
[trauncated plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j4D1v.png)

However; when I use HBox or Pane instead of SplitPane, everything works well.
 the code is here(I simplified it for better understanding)

> ```
> SplitPane splitPane = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));  
> Scene scene =new Scene(splitPane); 
> Pane pane = new HBox(); 
> pane.getChildren().add(A); 
> splitPane.getItems().add(pane); 
> primaryStage.setScene(scene);
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve it. It is a little bit tricky but in the subcode of sub-scene A; I use Stackpane as a root. I changed it to Group. everything works well.